# How to change url stucture using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mysqli

I developped  a dynamic website long time ago with mysqli and developped with no php framework and I want now to change the URL using htaccess I want to do this:

> www.website.com/post.php?id=1

to

> www.website.com/post/post_title.html

and the query I using is this:

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id_article='".$_GET['id']."'");
$articles = $query->fetch_object();
```

Is it possible to change the url?
If yes, do I have to change the query too?

Comment: I need an answer please !

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a .htaccess file in the root of the site

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule post/(.*) post.php?article_name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then you'll have to have post.php do a lookup to find `id_article` based on what is receives for `$_GET['article_name']`.

As a side note, the `$mysqli->query` code you posted is vulnerable to SQL injection because it doesn't call `addslashes` or `mysql_real_escape_string` on `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: and how do I link to the post ?
I want the URL like this : www.website.com/the-article-name.html

Comment: @Devstar I modeled this answer after the specific example you provided in your question - i.e. www.example.com/post/post_title.html.  Without the /post/ folder in the URL, the answer changes.

Comment: Its not working.
the .htaccess code replace all the URLs in the website to www.example.com/post/link.....